# Was bedeutet dieser Satz?

Tags: meaning

Ich kapiere den folgenden Satz einfach nicht. 
Ist der fettgedruckte Teil dieses Texts ein idiomatischer Ausdruck?

> Ohne Skrupel gelangt der clevere Taugenichts Selicour, **der glänzend
>   von den Früchten anderer Leute Arbeit lebt, zu Ehre und Glück**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Du hast hier einen Satz, in dem ein Relativsatz steckt.

Das ist der Hauptsatz:

> Ohne Skrupel gelangt der clevere Taugenichts Selicour zu Ehre und Glück.

Das bedeutet: Selicour ist ein Taugenichts, und er ist clever. Dieser Selicour gelangt zu Ehre und er gelangt auch zu Glück. Das macht er ohne Skrupel.

In dem Realtivsatz wird Selicour näher beschrieben:

> ..., der glänzend von den Früchten anderer Leute Arbeit lebt.

Der Relativsatz beginnt mit dem Relativpronomen »der«. Jedes Pronomen ist ein Stellvertreter für etwas anderes. Hier bezieht sich das Pronomen auf das Subjekt des Hauptsatzes, also auf »der clevere Taugenichts Selicour«.

Ich verkürze dieses Subjekt auf seinen Kern (»Selicour«), setze dieses Wort anstelle des Pronomens in den Relativsatz und bewege das Verb von der letzten auf die zweite Position im Satz, so dass daraus ein Hauptsatz entsteht. Das Ergebnis ist:

> Selicour lebt glänzend von den Früchten anderer Leute Arbeit.

Darin steht »anderer Leute Arbeit« im Genitiv und ist eine Ergänzung zu den Früchten. Einfacher sieht man das in diesem Satz:

> Er lebt von den Früchten der Arbeit. (Er lebt von wessen Früchten?)

Die Arbeit kann man nach demselben Schema wieder näher beschreiben, und das kann man wieder mit einer Geniv-Erweiterung machen. (Wessen Arbeit? Der Arbeit anderer Leute).

> Er lebt von den Früchten der Arbeit anderer Leute.

Diese Ergänzung (anderer Leute) kann man aber auch vorziehen, wodurch aber der Artikel verschwindet:

> Er lebt von den Früchten anderer Leute Arbeit.

Die Wendung

> glänzend von den Früchten der Arbeit leben

ist tatsächlich ein idiomatischer Ausdruck. Mit den *Früchten der Arbeit* sind aller Ergebnisse der Arbeit gemeint. »Glänzend« ist hier ein Synonym für »hervorragend«.

### Zusammenfassung

Der Satz bedeutet:

Eine Person, die Selicour heißt, hat folgende Eigenschaften:

- Er ist ein Taugenichts
- Er ist clever
- Er lebt glänzend von Früchten

Die Früchte sind das Ergebnis von Arbeit, diese Arbeit wurde aber von anderen Leuten verrichtet.

Dieser Selicor tut auch etwas in dem Satz:

> Selicour gelangt zu Ehre und Glück.

Comment: @userunknown: Danke, ich habe es gerade ergänzt.

Answer (score 5):

> Ohne Skrupel gelangt der clevere Taugenichts Selicour zu Ehre und Glück.

So lautet der Satz ansich.
Dann wird

> der glänzend von den Früchten anderer Leute Arbeit lebt

eingeschoben um den `Taugenichts Selicour` näher zu beschreiben.

Auch möglich:

> Ohne Skrupel gelangt der clevere Taugenichts Selicour, welcher
>   glänzend von den Früchten anderer Leute Arbeit lebt, zu Ehre und
>   Glück.

Also:

1. der clevere Taugenichts heißt Selicour
2. dieser gelangt zu Ehre und Glück
3. die Ehre und das Glück erlangt er ohne Skrupel
4. er lebt glänzend von den Früchten anderer Leute Arbeit
5. **das bedeutet:** dass er selber nichts unternehmen muss und auf Kosten anderer lebt

Comment: Besser. Inhaltlich halte ich nur Punkt 5 für zum Thema bezogen, siehe auch m. Kommentar zu Hübert Schönlast.

Comment: @userunknown: genau genommen hat er eine Frage gestellt, welche schlicht und einfach mit "ja" beantwortet werden kann.

Ich wollte ihm das ganze aber nochmal aus einem anderen Blickwinkel darstellen.

Comment: Ja, aber hast Du identifiziert, was seine Frage ist? Ich meine es ist das, was ich beantwortet habe und das würde ich als erstes angehen, nicht als letztes.

Comment: Ja ich hatte es so verstanden als würde er den ganzen Satz nicht verstehen.    Ich gelobe Besserung :)

Answer (score 4):

Ja, es ist eine stehende Redewendung, und zwar sowohl von den Früchten der Arbeit zu leben. Das bedeutet nicht, dass er von Obst lebt, sondern von dem, was die Arbeit anderer als Ertrag liefert.

Und glänzend von etwas leben heißt "sehr gut". It's brilliant. Auch das wird in diesem Kontext oft gebraucht.